# "was/were going to" equivalent in German

Tags: english-to-german, past-participle, future

English has **was/were going to** construct for past future. Can **wurde** be used for the same purpose? It is used for passive voice in the past. Can it be used for active voice as well?

Answer (score 1):

*She was going to read a book.*

English calls it *past future* but German uses tenses depending on the intent, not the relation of time frames. That's why this construct is rendered as

> Sie wollte gerade ein Buch lesen.

*"She wanted to read a book (but something interfered)."*

Funny enough, there's the *gerade* in the German sentence which —as usually— seems to match the continous aspect of *going* but it's not continous in English (that would call for *reading*) nor in German. It's a particle modifying *to be/wollen* in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

The future auxiliary *werden* only occurs in the present tense. There's lots of different ways to translate *was going to*, depending on the context.

> I wasn't going to give up. (plan)
> Ich **hatte** nicht **vor** aufzugeben.
>
> I was going to help you but never mind. (counterfactual)
> Ich **hätte** dir ja **geholfen**, aber vergiß es.
>
> He knew it was going to rain soon. (indirect speech)
> Er wußte, daß es bald **regnen** **würde**.

Comment: Die ersten beiden Beispiele lassen sich ebenso mit *wollen* übersetzen.

Answer (score 0):

The english construct *to be going to do something* is typically translated to *etwas vorhaben* or *etwas tun wollen*. Some examples are:

> I am going to visit Berlin.
>   
>   → Ich habe vor, Berlin zu besuchen.
>
> I was just going to call you.
>   
>   → Ich wollte dich gerade anrufen.